# How to use sha1sum to verify contents of a tarball

Tags: tar, sha1, sha1sum

When I run this command:

```
tar -xOzf oresoftware-npp-0.0.1002.tgz | sort | sha1sum
```

I get this:

```
fadc89dd523fd54299aed689a90f73243c5336b8  -
```

does anyone know what the trailing dash - is supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sha1sum` prints the SHA-1 hash, followed by the corresponding file name. In this case, it’s calculating the hash of the data on its standard input; it uses `-` as the file name to represent this.